# VPC connection between LDAP server onsite and LDAP client in Amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services, ldap, amazon-vpc

I currently have a VPC connection between LDAP server onsite and LDAP client in Amazon. However, after some time the connection starts to fail. I can notice that, since this appears for my user (even though I have access to the other user directory). When I restart the server, LDAP connection goes back to normal.

> ls: cannot access '/home/user2': Operation not permitted 
> total 76 
> drwxr-xr-x   4  root  root     0   May   4 05:54 . 
> drwxr-xr-x   20  root  root     4096   May   1 05:54 .. 
> drwxr-xr-x   139  user1  group1     69632   May   4 05:54 user1 
> d?????????   ?  ?  ?  ?   ? user2

This appears in the log, it looks like relevant information, but I do not know why this might be happening.

> Jun  7 03:17:01 machine_name CRON[1303070]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly) 
> Jun  7 03:20:16 machine_name nslcd[717]: [4bdd8a] <group/member="user2"> ldap_result() failed: Can't contact LDAP server: Connection reset by peer 
> Jun  7 03:20:16 machine_name nslcd[717]: [4bdd8a] <group/member="user2"> ldap_abandon() failed to abandon search: Can't contact LDAP server: Transport endpoint is not connected

Anyone with experience that can help with this issue?

Comment: Do you mean to say you have a “VPN” connection between  the two servers? A VPC or Virtual Private Cloud is not a mechanism that connects on-premise and cloud instances. With that said, it sounds like your VPN connection is failing to work after some time. But you didn’t provide any details of how that connection is configured or established. But, generally speaking, it means you have a mismatch in VPN parameters on the two sides of the tunnel. Or an issue with dead peer detection or keep-alives.

Comment: Do you have a dual tunnel VPN set up? Looks like you're having connectivity issues, but you'll need to edit your question to provide more information if you want more help.